# Validate text input to match Canadian postal code (e.g. "A1S2S3")

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

here  error is  can't enter any character :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#t').keypress(function(e){
    var txt = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    console.log(txt + ' : ' + e.which);
    if(!txt.match(/^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{1} *\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}$/)){
      return false;
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<input type="text" id="postCode" placeholder="Enter postcode">
<span id="result"></span>

var pattern = /[ABCEFGHJKLMNPRSTVXY][0-9][ABCEFGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][0-9][ABCEFGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][0-9]/,
$result = $("#result");

$('#postCode').keyup(function(){
  var val = this.value
  if(!val.match(pattern)){
    $result.text("invalid");
  } else {
    $result.text("valid");      
  }
});
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/nL3k67vn/)

Comment: I would only add a \s*? between the first 3 and the last 3 characters, to account for the common use of writing a space in between. Like in the North Pole's postal code: H0H 0H0

Comment: Yeah, no idea about the regex. I'm sure it could do with some work, though.

Comment: but how to restrict input in textbox which not match with regex..?

Comment: Validate the form when it is submitted. Don't try to do this on the fly.

Comment: Look its an easy to use input pattern https://jsfiddle.net/iffikhan30/nfh3k75y/5/

Answer (score 1):

`pattern` attribute is *widely* supported now. So you can just add it to the `<input>`

```
<input pattern="^[A-Za-z]\d[A-Za-z][ -]?\d[A-Za-z]\d$" />
```